# Trying to combine two cmdlets and output to an excel spreadsheet

Tags: powershell

I'm new to this forum and I apologize if I may have left anything out.

I'm trying to combine two cmdlets(Get-cdmGroupProfile and get-adgroupmember)  and get the results(Get-cdmGroupProfile(returns groups from an application called Centrify ) and Get-adgroupmember(which gets group members from the  from the cmdlets exported to an excel spreadsheet.

From what I have read ,not all cmdlets can be accept piped input and that is where the need for calculated properties comes in.

I have done this a couple times before( included script at the very bottom of the posting) where I created a calculated property and 
was able to get the exported results in an Excel spreadsheet.

However when I tried the code I used before ,it didn't give me the results I was looking for.

After doing some more research I tried to use the calculated properties as such below and then pass it to the select object.

The script just keeps running and doesn't appear to stop. I removed the result variable that I assigned the foreach loop to and removed it the result from being piped into the excel spreadsheet and noticed the results weren't exactly what I wanted.

I was hoping to maybe find a more efficient way of doing this.

I was able to get it exported to an excel spreadsheet ,but it just shows the results from the array which repeats the values ,but doesn't list them like I would like.

```
I would like the following script to output the following information below 

Zonename    AD Linux Group   Centrify group
PROD ZONE      Group1             Group A
PROD ZONE      Group2             Group B 
TEST ZONE      GROUP5             GROUP D
```

---

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Centrify\Inputpega.csv

$result = foreach($item in $list) {


$adgroupmember = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $item.Group

$centrifygprofile = Get-CdmGroupProfile -Zone $item.DistinguishedName 

Get-CdmGroupProfile -Zone $item.DistinguishedName |%{

Get-ADGroupmember -identity  $item.Group 

$Properties = @(
@{Name='ZoneName';Expression={$centrifygprofile.Zone}}, 
@{Name=' Centrify Group';Expression={$centrifygprofile.name}}, 
@{Name='AD Linux GROUP' ;Expression={$adgroupmember.name}},
)

$result | Export-Csv C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Results\results4.csv -
 NoTypeInformation
```

Results that I'm getting -

```
ZoneName             : {OU=TEST ZONE ,OU=TEST Zone 
One,OU=Zones,OU=TEST,DC=TEST,DC=com,OU=PROD ZONE,OU=PROD Zone 
One,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com,
OU=PROD ZONE,OU=PROD Zone 
One,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com,OU=Unix,DC=PRODk,DC=com, OU=PROD 
ZONE,OU=PROD Zone One,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com...}
Centrify Group      : {group1@prod.com, group2@prod.com, group3@prod.com, 
group4@prod.com...}
PROD_GROUPS,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,OU=PROD,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com
AD Linux Group       : {group6, group7, group8, group9...

ZoneName             : {OU=TEST ZONE ,OU=TEST Zone 
One,OU=Zones,OU=TEST,DC=TEST,DC=com,OU=PROD ZONE,OU=PROD Zone 
One,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com,
OU=PROD ZONE,OU=PROD Zone 
One,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com,OU=Unix,DC=PRODk,DC=com, OU=PROD 
ZONE,OU=PROD Zone One,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com...}
Centrify Group      : {group1@prod.com, group2@prod.com, group3@prod.com, 
group4@prod.com...}
PROD_GROUPS,OU=Zones,OU=PROD,OU=PROD,OU=PROD,DC=PROD,DC=com
AD Linux Group       : {group6, group7, group8, group9...
```

---

This is a script I have used multiple before where I was able to combine multiple commands and export the data I wanted to an excel spreadsheet by using calculated properties.

```
 $list = Import-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\dn2.csv


 $finalzpa = Foreach($item in $list){

 $zonezpa = Get-CdmZpaSetting -Zone $item.DistinguishedName

 $zoneset = Get-CdmZone -dn $item.DistinguishedName

 Get-CdmZone -Dn $item.DistinguishedName | %{

 Get-CdmZpaSetting -Zone $item.DistinguishedName |

 Select-Object @{Name='Userenabled';Expression={$zonezpa.UserEnabled}},
               @{Name='Provisioning Groups enabled';Expression=
{$zonezpa.GroupEnabled}},
               @{Name='ZoneName' ;Expression={$zoneset.Name}},
               @{Name='User Source';Expression={$zonezpa.UserSource}},
               @{Name='Group Source';Expression={$zonezpa.GroupSource}},
               @{Name='Distinguished Name';Expression=
 {$item.DistinguishedName}}





 }}



 $finalzpa | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation 
 C:\Users\Desktop\zonesautoinfo.csv
```

---

```
$adgroupmember | gm


TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal

Name       MemberType       Definition                                                                                                                         

 ----        ----------       ----------                                                                                                                         

 Contains     Method     bool Contains(string propertyName)                                                                                                 

 Equals         Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                     

GetEnumerator  Method     System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator                                                                            

GetHashCode    Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                  

GetType        Method                type GetType()                                                                                                                     

ToString          Method                string ToString()                                                                                                                  

Item              ParameterizedProperty 
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection Item(string 
propertyName) {get;}                                    
distinguishedName Property              System.String distinguishedName 
{get;set;}                                                                                         

name              Property              System.String name {get;}                                                                                                          

objectClass       Property              System.String objectClass {get;set;}                                                                                               

objectGUID        Property              System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, 
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
objectGUID {get;set;}
SamAccountName    Property              System.String SamAccountName 
{get;set;}                                                                                            

SID               Property              
System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier SID {get;set;}
```

---

```
$centrifygprofile | gm


TypeName: Centrify.DirectControl.PowerShell.Types.CdmGroupProfile

Name                 MemberType Definition                                                                

----                 ---------- ----------                                                                

Equals               Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                            

GetHashCode          Method     int GetHashCode()                                                         

GetType              Method     type GetType()                                                            

ToString             Method     string ToString()                                                         

CanonicalName        Property   string CanonicalName {get;}                                               

Computer             Property   
Centrify.DirectControl.PowerShell.Types.CdmManagedComputer Computer {get;}
Domain               Property   string Domain {get;}                                                      

Gid                  Property   System.Nullable[long] Gid {get;}                                          

Group                Property   
Centrify.DirectControl.PowerShell.Types.CdmGroup Group {get;}             
IsHierarchical       Property   bool IsHierarchical {get;}                                                

IsMembershipRequired Property   System.Nullable[bool] IsMembershipRequired 
{get;}                         
IsOrphan             Property   bool IsOrphan {get;}                                                      

IsSfu                Property   bool IsSfu {get;}                                                         

Name                 Property   string Name {get;}                                                        

PreferredServer      Property   string PreferredServer {get;}                                             

Zone                 Property   
Centrify.DirectControl.PowerShell.Types.CdmZone Zone {get;}
```

Comment: when combining multiple items (ad group members for example) into one property will cause it to need to be expanded. CSV can't handle nested properties. an easy solution would be to just export it to xml.

Comment: Another option would be a foreach loop inside the current loop to perform the $properties grab on each individual member

Comment: I think what would help get an answer, is displaying an example of what you want your output to look like :D

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for the reply. I made multiple edits. Just an fyi ,the Get-CdmGroupProfile -Zone $item.DistinguishedName |Select-Object Zone,Name works fine by itself and the Get-ADGroupmember -identity  $item.Group works fine by themselves. Which is good ,but when I try to obtain the properties via calculated properties it seems to display what I'm looking for ,but it shows essentially what the array of groups when exported to a csv file.Ex{Group1,Group2,Group3....} will show on every line. Not sure if that helps.